# How to install Gnome Software Center in Ubuntu Gnome 15.04?

Tags: gnome, 15.04, compiling

How can I install the Gnome Software Center?

I have found the .tat.xz file on Softpedia

http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Software-Distribution/GNOME-Software-102470.shtml

but am unable to build in on Ubuntu 15.04.  ./configure gives errors.

Comment: Ubuntu software center is already installed... Can't you use that?

Comment: @Tim "Gnome Software Center" not "Ubuntu Software Center"

Comment: @A.B. What is  the difference?

Comment: @Tim https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Software

Comment: The Ubuntu Software Centre is very bloated and slow.  I have removed it completely from my system and replaced it with App Grid.  However this is also needs work.  The Gnome Software center seems sleeker.

Answer (score 2):

A better way is a build with [JHBuild](https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/3.15/jhbuild.html) and `checkinstall`:

```bash
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
git clone git://git.gnome.org/jhbuild
cd jhbuild
./autogen.sh
make
sudo checkinstall --pkgversion $(date +%Y%m%d)
```

From here it is expensive:

```bash
~/.local/bin/jhbuild sysdeps --install
~/.local/bin/jhbuild build gnome-software
```